# Filter a F[List[Int]] using an Int => F[Boolean] where F is generic

Tags: scala, generic-programming, scala-cats

I'm trying to define an abstract algebra that will allow me to defer choosing what Monad I will use to wrap an effectful operation (IO, Task, Future, etc) until I run the program.

```
trait MyAlg[F[_]]
  def isValid(v: int): F[Boolean]
  def getElements(): F[List[Int]]
  def filterValidElements(vs: F[List[Int]]): F[List[Int]]
```

Imagine that I need to do something possibly side-effecting in `isValid`, like check the db.

What would be nice is if I could leave `isValid` and `getElements` abstract --- so that for example one implementation could connect to a database and another could refer to a mock for testing --- but define a generic `filterValidElements` so I don't need to re-impliment the same function for both cases. Something like this:

```
def filterValidElements(es: F[List[Int]]]): F[List[Int]] = 
      es.map(
        elems => elems.map(
          e => (e, isValid(e))).collect{
            case (e, F(true)) => e
       })
```

However,`F` is generic, so it doesn't provide `map` and doesn't have a constructor.

Of course, I can't explicity set `F` to be a Monad, for example like

```
trait MyAlg[F: cats.Monad]
```

because traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds.

Is there any way to write my `filterValidElements` function, leaving `isValid` abstract and `F` generic?

I am pretty new with this style, so I may be going about this entirely the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add implicit parameters specifying that you can do `map` (i.e. `Functor`) and `pure` aka `point` (i.e. `InvariantMonoidal`). For example you can make it `Applicative` or `Monad`.

```
import cats.{Functor, InvariantMonoidal}
import cats.syntax.functor._
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait MyAlg[F[_]] {
  def isValid(v: Int): F[Boolean]
  def getElements(): F[List[Int]]
  def filterValidElements(es: F[List[Int]])(implicit functor: Functor[F], im: InvariantMonoidal[F]): F[List[Int]] =
    es.map(
      elems => elems.map(
        e => (e, isValid(e))).collect{
          case (e, fb) if fb == im.point(true) => e
        })
}
```

Comment: This was very close to working. I had to change the es.map to Functor[F].map(es) and then it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you didn't `import cats.syntax.functor._`. If you do you should be able to write `es.map(..)`.

Comment: Definitely have that import.